# Client side proxy server! Can you do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, websocket, proxy

I have a WebApp(PHP) to which the user sends requests to my server, it processes this data and queries on a social network and returns the information to the user.
But I'm having problems where social networks are blocking the IP of my server because of the volume of queries.
Below is my current flow:

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to return this information to my user's browser and make queries from his computer, since it is a new and residential IP.
I do not know if you can make a proxy server with websocket where you would use the user's machine to send the requests.

Here is the flow you want:

[image]

Maybe have some way using websocket with a node.js server.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a client side proxy as such. Protocols built on top of connection-oriented(TCP) protocol will need a valid IP to get response. Establishing a two-way connection will become difficult once you send different request IPs. Even if you are able to do this by some kind of IP spoofing, which I am unaware of, you'll most likely will not be able to have the solution at scale for your app's users.

The best known method would be to use some kind of desktop based solution for such problems and thereby having organic request IPs. If that is not what you want, then you can use proxy servers, that might even be good if you have fewer users, but that might not scale.